# Can I apply night mode without restarting the activity?

Tags: android, dialog, themes, android-darkmode

While creating an Android app, I want to create a function that allows you to set the dark mode in a dialog window created from a fragment. As a result of finding a way to set the dark mode, almost all developers use the restart activity. Is there a way to apply the dark mode immediately without restart? This is the dark mode application code in the dialog window inside the fragment I am currently using.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private var dialog: AlertDialg? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false)

        if (AppCompatDelegete.getDefulatNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
           context!!.setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme)
        } else {
           context!!.setTheme(R.style.LightTheme)
        }

        view.darkMode.setOnClickListener {
            val v = LayoutInfalter.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_dark, null)
            builder.setView(v)
            dialog = builder.create()
            dialog.show()

            v.selectMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, id ->
                when (id) {
                    R.id.light -> {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        
                    }
                    R.id.dark -> {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking the `darkMode` Button in the `view` that inflates `fragment_my` creates a `v` that inflates `dialog_dark`. Inside `v`, there is `selectMode` made of RadioGroup, and inside there are `light` radio button and `dark` radio button. When I made it as above, I confirmed that it restarts from the MainActivity when `light` or `dark` is clicked. Is it possible to immediately apply the theme change every time `ligth` or `dark` is clicked without turning off the dialog window?

Answer (score -2):

This can be done in Kotlin by misusing a visibility modifier.

Create a Kotlin file (like `AppCompatExtensions.kt`) with the following contents:

```
@file:Suppress("PackageDirectoryMismatch")
package androidx.appcompat.app

/**
 * Misuses a package-private function to remove an activity
 */
fun doNotRestartThisActivity(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
    AppCompatDelegate.removeActivityDelegate(activity.delegate)
}
```

Now in your activity, just before calling `AppCompatDelegate.setNightMode(MODE)` call your new method:

```
doNotRestartThisActivity(this)
```

This will remove the current activity from the list of activities which need to be restarted.